# Problem Integrating Solr into postgresSQL

Tags: search, solr, solrcloud

Based on the documentation, we will need to create and upload a new configset to zookeeper by including dataimport handler lib in solrconfig.xml and a new data-config.xml. Here are the details after the deployment is made.

Scenario:

1. Using config API to upload a new customized configsets (including dataimport handler lib) with postgres info
2. Create a new collection using configsets (as in solr UI screenshot)
   [solr UI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pubDt.png)
3. Getting error (in the response screenshot)
   [response screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOo8I.jpg)

Blocking step:
We did try to enable authentication, by using a security.json file.
We are using solr cloud mode. So the security.json should be placed in the zookeeper, where we are facing difficulty to do so.

Questions:
We tried to include security.json in the new configsets and planned to copy it to zookeeper. Is that the correct way? If YES, what should be the subsequent steps? If NO, what should be the correct way?

Notes:
There should be different setups between SolrCloud and standalone modes. We are using Solr cloud mode managed by zookeeper. So there should be limited access for us to directly modify the file and folder in solr.

Comment: DIH has been removed from Solr9, so I wouldn't base any new solutions around it (it's still available as an external module) - but instead write your own small application that connects to postgres and exports to Solr.

Comment: `security.json` is not part of a config set. It's a file placed on the root of your zookeeper (i.e. for Solr). You can use the bundled `bin/solr` tool to upload it in the correct location: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/authentication-and-authorization-plugins.html#using-security-json-with-solr